# How to run designer software

Tags: centos

I've installed Centos not so long ago, installed it both with KDE and Gnome.  Also installed NVidia drivers. So I have no idea which Linux Distro is good, but I like CentOS, sometimes embarrassed with this alt-f1-f8 switches when the system hangs, because my computer got only 1.5 GB memory, DDR1 xor 2 don't know exactly. So I've downloaded the DBDesigner tool for creating DB schemas and reverse engineering, and when I'm trying to install it the message comes:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: DBDesigner
       Requires: libXft.so.1
Error: Package: DBDesigner
       Requires: libborunwind.so.6.0
Error: DBDesigner
       Requires: libodbc.so.1
```

Can you tell me how to install the needed libraries??

Answer (score 1):

The short of it - you can't.

It looks like this software is *VERY* old - Version 4 (from their website) talks about a 2.4 Kernel, and recommends Redhat 7.3 which is well over 10 years old - and appears to be designed for Windows (it libborunwind is/was found as part of a library for Borland Software), so I doubt you will get the software running just using the RPM.

Similarly, I tried downloading the ".tgz" file, and it is looking for libraries which are simply too old.

Comment: In that case, look around for some other package doing this. I'm sure at http://www.postgresql.org or the other RDBMS sites you'll find something. Or look at the `*.edu` sites for database courses, they'll probably suggest someting for use by the <strikeout>victi</strikeout>students.

Comment: Oh, I'm not advanced in Google search, it always offers me mysql-workbench and I need this software because it can regallery (autolayout) all tables, and to export to my needed format. Maybe I should use wine version? Don't know, because don't want to loose these opportunity. Best regards